# I Have An Encrypted Message

Tags: substitution-cipher

I am a newbie to cryptography and am stuck on decrypting a message. This message was received from a friend and I would like to crack it in order to respond. I have decrypted part of it but am unable to complete the rest due to my incompetence.

This is the message:

"**ITKT'L Q LTEKTZ, O SGCT VHAHIGV!**"

This is what I have decrypted so far:

"**HERE'S A SECRET, I ...E ....H..!**"

Firstly, I used the apostrophe as a guide to what the letter could be. The word itself is too long or too short to be a 'can't' or 'would't' word and therefore I thought it was an 's' instead of a 't'. This means that the letter 'l' is 's'.

Next, the most common letter used in the English alphabet is 'e'. The letter 't' appears more times than any other so I presumed that this was and 'e'. Thus meaning that 't' is equal to 'e'.

After that, I took a stab in the dark and guessed the first word as 'here's'. The next word is a single letter which has to be either 'i' or 'a'. With the first word now being 'here's', I assumed that the single letter after had to be 'a' and therefore the next single letter is 'i'.

This is as far as I have got and I am now stuck on the ending. I have realised that the final word contains two 'v' (one at the start and end). Also there is two 'h'. There is also a 'g' which, once cracked, could help to reveal the the other word.

I cannot determine the type of cipher this message has used and I am unable to crack the final words simply because I am a newbie and don't really know what I'm looking for.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This may actually be a suitable question, but in order to make it one, please document what you've tried and what you think which kind of cipher this is and why exactly you couldn't break the last few letters. Without all of this information, this question is unlikely to be helpful to anybody else ever and thus would be closed as "request for analyzing or deciphering data"

Comment: I have edited with all the information on how I got to the stage I'm at. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: The next-to-last word might be love. ​ ​